# standard file format(s) to represent database schemas

Tags: xml, postgresql, entity-relationship, database-schema, information-schema

Is there any standard or at least very common file format to serialize the schema of a database? It seems that every db schema tool comes with its own file format for this to list tables, their columns, indexes and the rest.

This question has been asked before in 2009 without a satisfying answer: [Standard database neutral XSD to describe a relational database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019463/standard-database-neutral-xsd-to-describe-a-relational-database-schema)

Comment: +1 You're quite correct every tool has its own format....

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the only standard file format is that of SQL.  Every app has its own format, which is to be expected since the format is probably based on internal representations of the data to some extent.